# Cross-compiling a MPICH library for Android NDK

Tags: android, openssl, arm, cross-compiling, mpich

My goal is to run MPICH on Android phones. I'm using Debian Jessie. I thought that I'll achieve that following this tutorial:
http://hex.ro/wp/projects/personal-cloud-computing/compiling-mpich2-for-android-and-running-on-two-phones/
but instead of creating toolchain with Buildroot I decided to create it from Android NDK, as on this site:
http://www.threadstates.com/articles/2013/setting-up-an-android-cross-compiling-environment-with-the-ndk.html
 I tried to use MPICH library versions 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 3.0.4 and configure it using command:

```
sudo CFLAGS=" -march=armv5 -mfpu=vfp -static "
 CC=/home/cerbia/android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc ./configure
 --prefix=/home/cerbia/old --host=arm-linux --with-pm=smpd --disable-f77 --disable-fc
```

but I still had this kind of error:

> configure: error: SMPD requires MD5 support, and configure could not
>   find either md5_calc in md5.h or MD5 in openssl/md5.h

I found, that it is connected with openssl version and I tried to follow this instruction:

> Download, compile, modify and install OpenSSL to the NDK directory. cd ~ wget www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0g.tar.gz tar xvzf
>
> openssl-1.0.0g.tar.gz cd openssl-1.0.0g ./config no-asm shared --prefix=$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr
>
> edit Makefile:
>    CC= arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6
>
> CFLAG= -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DOPENSSL_N -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -fPIC
>
> DEPFLAG= -DOPENSSL_NO_GMP -DOPENSSL_NO_JPAKE -DOPENSSL_NO_MD2 -DOPENSSL_NO_R C5 -DOPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 -DOPENSSL_NO_STORE
>
> PEX_LIBS=
>
> EX_LIBS= -ldl
>
> EXE_EXT=
>
> ARFLAGS=
>
> AR= arm-linux-gnueabi-ar $(ARFLAGS) r
>
> RANLIB= arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
>
> NM= arm-linux-gnueabi-nm
>
> PERL= /usr/bin/perl
>
> TAR= tar
>
> TARFLAGS= --no-recursion
>
> MAKEDEPPROG= gcc
>
> LIBDIR=lib

Than instead of HIPL I tried to cross-compile MPICH in the analogous way as below

> Download and cross-compile HIPL. cd ~ bzr co lp:hipl trunk cd trunk edit configure.ac and comment out all AM_CFLAGS autoreconf --install
>
> ./configure --disable-gcc-warn --disable-firewall -host=arm-linux
>
> CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6
>
> CPPFLAGS="-I$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include"
>
> CFLAGS="-nostdlib"
>
> LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib,-L$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib"
>
> LIBS="-lc" make make all-am make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mkomu/projects/hipl-bzr/arm'   CC lib/core/builder.lo In file
>
> included from lib/core/debug.h:34:0,
>
> ```
>              from lib/core/crypto.h:43,
>
>              from lib/core/builder.c:100: lib/core/protodefs.h:917:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t'
> ```
>
> lib/core/protodefs.h:929:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t'
>
> lib/core/protodefs.h:1027:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t'
>
> lib/core/protodefs.h:1036:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t'
>
> lib/core/protodefs.h:1043:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t'
>
> lib/core/protodefs.h:1054:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t'
>
> lib/core/protodefs.h:1055:5: error: unknown type name 'in_port_t' ...
>
> it comes from site: bugs.launchpad.net/hipl/+bug/715126

but I got the same errors as person there..

> make[8]: Wejście do katalogu
>   `/home/cerbia/old/mpich2-1.3.2/src/mpid/ch3/channels/nemesis/nemesis/netmod/tcp'
>   CC              tcp_finalize.c In file included from
>   tcp_finalize.c:7:0: tcp_impl.h:108:89: error: unknown type name
>   'in_port_t' make[8]: *** [tcp_finalize.o] Błąd 1

Do you have any advices what I should try to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, `in_port_t` is typedefed as `uint16_t` in `netinet/in.h`. The only place this typedef is used is in the definition of `sockaddr_in`.

The Android NDK does not define or use `in_port_t`, but instead uses `unsigned short int`. To compile code using the Android NDK, either `typedef in_port_t` or replace it with `unsigned short int`.