# cross compiling using Android toolchains

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, mpich

I need to compile mpich for android , I used NDK arm-linux-andoirdeabi-4.8 toolchain to cross compile mpi , I did the following

```
export PATH="$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:$PATH"
export SYS_ROOT="$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/"
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"


./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi  --prefix=/Crosscompile2/jni/mpich/ LIBS="-lc -lgcc " --disable-shared --disable-fortran --disable-cxx
```

but I got the following error:

```
checking for pthread_key_create in -lpthread... no
checking checkpointing library... configure: error: pthreads is required for checkpointing, but was not found
configure: error: src/pm/hydra configure failed
```

when I added -lpthread

```
LIBS="-lc -lgcc -lpthread"
```

it didn't compile

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is special in that it implements pthreads, but does not have a separate libpthread.a. The easy workaround is to [add an empty library to your toolchain `usr/lib`](https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/x264-devel/2013-March/009941.html)

```
$AR q $SYS_ROOT/usr/lib/libpthread.a
```

before running `./configure`

Comment: I have tried the following 
/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar q  $SYS_ROOT/usr/lib/libthread.a
then
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi  --prefix=home/doha/workspace/Crosscompile2/jni/mpich/ LIBS="-lc -lgcc " --disable-shared --disable-fortran --disable-cxx --enable-pic --extra-ldflags="-L."
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--extra-ldflags=-L.'
if I removed the ldflag I get the same old error pthread required
I also want to know the location of the file that to be patched "cpu.c"

Comment: it should be lib**pthread**.a! And you don't need `--extra-ldflags="-L."` here.

Comment: yes libpthread ,it worked but make actually failed :
`topology-linux.c:1874: error: undefined reference to 'getline'`
`topology-linux.c:195: error: undefined reference to 'faccessat'`
I don't know the location of ('cpu.c') the file to be patched

Comment: Did you check [*cross-compiling mpich for Android*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111281/cross-compiling-a-mpich-library-for-android-ndk)? Generally speaking, if a library is not configured for  *bionic* runtime, porting it may require very advanced programming skills. This specific project depends on other libraries, which makes the task even more challenging. The [alternative approach](http://hex.ro/wp/projects/personal-cloud-computing/compiling-mpich2-for-android-and-running-on-two-phones/), not using android toolchain, may be easier.

Comment: Thanks @alex that was very helpful, I have been trying to use buildroot but there is some link issues as well , mean while I will mark this as the right answer for the pthread issue in android toolchain .

Answer (score 1):

For the libpthread problems,  you have 2 options.

1. sed out the requirement from the configure/makefiles since pthread is included in bionics libc

Or

2. Create a libpthead that's a symlink to libc

cd $SYSROOT/usr/lib

ln -s libc.a libpthread.a